# Should I change the default folder for uploads?

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload

PHP 7 uses the default system folder (/tmp) to store uploaded files.
PHP allows you to change the settings and change the upload destination directory. Some sites indicate to change this folder to another one, since the /tmp permission is 777.

OWASP has nothing listed in the security recommendations. Should I really worry about changing this folder to another one or there are no risks?

Comment: Technically the /tmp directory permission is 1777; the sticky bit being set to protect users' files from other users.  That does offer some mitigation against the sort of attacks that might concern you.

Comment: Moreover, systemd is probably configured to give the web server (since you are talking about uploading files) its own local `/tmp`